# Is there a packet sniffer that can be limited to one single program?

Tags: wireshark, packet-capture

I've been using Wireshark for a while now to analyze a few programs. Is there a way that I can limit Wireshark to sniff only one program? Or is there another program that does something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sniffing a web application, you should try to use HttpFox, which is a Firefox plugin. It only show net traffic from the current website.

Answer (score 2):

[tracedump](http://mutrics.iitis.pl/tracedump) is an open source packet sniffer available for Linux, which can do exactly what was asked in the original question; it's free.

Answer (score 1):

Using Wireshark you can filter by destination port number or IP address. For example, Mail clients usually use ports 25 and 110 for sending and receiving emails.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for Windows or mac...?

If Windows then the answer is yes.You can use Microsoft Network Monitoring tool..

But for mac i did not find any useful tool yet...am still searching...

In mac OS X you can use the following command and that will give you the list of ports used by the application.

```
    lsof -i |grep firefox|grep Established|awk -F "[ :]*" '{print $10}' |cut -c 1-5 >>/Users/..../Desktop/name.txt
```

Use these ports to filter the wireshark pcap...

Done...!